# Testing file on ipad device gives error

Tags: ios, ipad

I am testing ipad app on device but it gives the error when i test it the execultabe was signed with invalid entilements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using your Development Profile to sign the app in Build Settings, rather than an Ad Hoc or other Distribution Profile.